# How does website monitoring works?

Tags: web

I am trying to understand how does monitoring websites for changes works and what are concepts used behind it.
I can think of creating a crawler which crawls the whole website, compare the crawled webpage to the one store in the database and overwrite the old page in html if the webpage has been updated or store it in database if it doesn't exist.
So here are my questions:
1- How can I compare 2 webpages if they're same? Do i need to compare the string equivalents of the webpages character by character?
2- Do I need to crawl the whole website? let's suppose the html pages of a website are 5 Gb in size and i want to detect for changes in the website on hourly basis so crawling and downloading a 5 Gb data every hour is going to eat up a lot of bandwidth.

I can write code, i just want to know the general practice used for monitoring a website.

Thanks alot.

Comment: I think it uses Last-Modification header to determinate any changes. And if there is crawl request, it crawls it all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to store a hash of the page in your database, rather than the whole page as HTML. This would allow you to check the value against the one stored. But you'd still have to "read" the page to do this so yes, a site that is 5GB would still "download" the 5GB to do this.

I'm assuming you'd only hold onto the meta-data for the page, URL, last updated, the content hash, etc, you haven't really said why you might be doing this.

Perhaps as Martin Joneš has suggested most just fetch the page headers and check the Last-Modification parameter.

I'm also assuming you're doing this only on a site you own/run. Nothing I dislike more than those naff "marketing" bots that crawl my sites, increasing my bandwidth usage with zero value for me. They're just eating my bandwidth for the heck of it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. I am just doing it for education purpose and trying to learn how does crawling work, especially how does search engines crawl the millions of websites. Also, the Last-modification header was new for me. I think it can only be used to test last modification time of a web page and not a whole website. Is it possible to test if a website has added *new* webpage/content using something like headers etc rather than crawling the whole website?

Comment: To do this you could check for a sitemap.xml, if provided you could compare that against an older version, you have already stored. Assuming the site is adding all pages to it's sitemap.xml, which they don't all do.

But other than that, there really isn't an easy way. Pages are entities unto themselves so there isn't a central check for them, other than the sitemap, if implemented.

Search engines use the sitemap, but they also index words on the page so they are clearly downloading the page in its entirety. They also use the hyperlinking to determine site structure.